# Have application wait for initial XHR loading?

Tags: angular

In my app, I have an initialization XHR request and I'd like to have the entire application wait for this XHR to complete. Think of it as initializing the application.

I'm using `angular-cli` so I have the standard files and structure.

At the top, I have `app.component.html` which only contains one line: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

I've tried to get a route guard to work, but those are check when a route is used.

Any points would be useful.

Comment: Something like [this](https://hackernoon.com/hook-into-angular-initialization-process-add41a6b7e)?

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason not to use HttpClient??

I use an Observable for that. That's one way to go about it.

In your service file:

1 - Create a BehaviorSubject 
`letThemKnow = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);` 
2 - Return an observable from the function that you call HttpClient or XHR similar to the code below.

`fetchData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<T>(URL). 
    });`

in `app.components.ts` and inside `ngOnInit` call fetchData() and subscribe for that

`this.yourService.fetchData().subscribe( () => {
    this.yourservice.letThemKnow.next(true);
});`

then whenever on your app that you need to start after the data or application has been ready. Just subscribe and check for TRUE on that service.

something similar to this. 
    `this.yourservice.letThemKnow.subscribe((state: boolean) => {
        if (state) {
            //do this
    }`

Here for RxJs
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/